How do I know if a user has used a similar string when changing the password?
I see that there's a security requirement in some audit systems that says "the user cannot change the password to a similar string". For example, simply changing 123456 to 123456! should not be allowed.
But if I am storing the password in the form of hashed string in my database, it seems there's no way for me to know if the two strings are similar. Even if a slight change is applied can lead to huge difference.
I wonder if there's a way for me to achieve this, other than storing the password somewhere else. So that the users' password can always be safe even if my server is hacked.

This is not a recommendation according to the latest NIST guidelines. You should probably not implement this unless you need to comply with outdated requirements. Also passwords should not expire anymore and so on.

When changing a password, usually the user should enter both the old and the new password - so you have cleartext versions of both

How about hash the password and compare it with recent hashed passwords?

Basically dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218259/how-does-the-system-know-when-a-password-contains-parts-of-a-previous-password (as autorecommended) and see links there

@YoushaAleayoub It won't work if the user forgets the password and is trying to add a new one in the password reset process.

@GaborLengyel Thanks! I would probably just keep it hashed and only prevent users using the exact same password (which means the hash is the same) when they are updating it. Perhaps make it an answer so I can accept it?

@dave_thompson_085 Thanks! I would probably just keep it hashed and only prevent users using the exact same password (which means the hash is the same) when they are updating it.

Comparing hashes may not work when you use 'salt', unless you use the same salt for both
